# Why is Math.Round() not resulting as I expect in C#

Tags: c#, rounding

Why does Math.Round(1.444445M, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) return 1.44 instead of 1.45?

Comment: Exactly what makes you think that Math.Round() isn't "accurate"? 1.444xxx to two decimal places *SHOULD* give you 1.44!  Look here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding

Comment: `1.444445` is _closer_ to `1.44` than to `1.45`. Try doing some subtractions on a calculator.

Comment: community seems to be downvoting this question because you're asserting that is not accurate - you're asserting the issue is with the function.  I think you could improve this question by changing the title to "Why is Math.Round() not resulting as I expect",  the issue remains the expectation, but doesn't make a false assertion.

Comment: math.round is accurate; your understanding of rounding is not.

Comment: given the title has been edited, I want to stipulate that "accurate" in this context is/was really in regards to "approximation".  In comparison of the result of `Math.Round` to an expected result (the basis of this question).  it is at matter of being "more or less accurate approximation" or "better or worse approximation".

Answer (score 1):

Because this is how rounding works.

Like @Sweeper said, `1.444445` is closer to `1.44` than to `1.45`.

[image]

1. You take a number `1.444445`.
2. Now you want to round it to 2 decimal places, so select 2 digits after dot: `1.[44]4445`
3. Then look at the next digit after `[44]`, which is `4` also
4. 4 < 5, so rounding should not be applied. Edit: I mean it will stay the same [44], rest of number will be zeroed ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation seems to be similar to this recursive function that will result in `1.45` after a sequence of `Math.Round`.

```
double RecursiveMathRound(double val, int precisionLevel, int decimalPlace)
{
    return (precisionLevel <= decimalPlace)
       ? Math.Round(val, precisionLevel, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
       : RecursiveMathRound(Math.Round(val, precisionLevel, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), precisionLevel - 1, decimalPlace);
}

RecursiveMathRound(1.444445d, 5, 2);
```

However, any form of rounding is less 'accurate' or 'correct' then a value that was not rounded at all. The `RecursiveMathRound` snippet above produces a less accurate or correct approximation because of the series of rounding occurrences.

Comment: I don't want to add it to the answer (because I'm unsure), but this may be termed and an example of a "Round-off error" as it relates to iterative computation on finite precision.  It's probably in the study of numerical analysis (branch of mathematics which studies how errors propagate in algorithms) ref https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/mathsys/courses/msc/ma934/resources/notes1.pdf